# How to find dropdown selected value with in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

View code:

```
<div id="maindiv"> 
    for(i=1;i<3;i++)
    {   
        <div id="subdiv">    
            @html.dropdownlistfor(m=>m.id,new selectlist((viewbag.country) as selectlist,"Value","Text"),new{@class="country"})    
            @html.dropdownlistfor(m=>m.stateid,new selectlist((viewbag.state) as selectlist,"Value","Text"),new{@class="state"})
            <input type="button" value="remove" class="remove">
        </div>
     }
</div>
```

Button click event:

```
$("#maindiv").on("click",".remove",function(e){
     alert($(".country")[0].selectedIndex);  // This jquery returns only zero
     $this.parent('div').remove();
});
```

I need to country dropdown selected Index

Comment: Missing qoutes `$("#maindiv")`

Comment: Not related but `ViewBag.country` is already a `SelectList` so why are you creating a new `SelectList` from it (just pointless extra overhead) - its just `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.id, (SelectList)ViewBag.country, new{ @class="country" })`

Comment: The edit shows the code is not in a loop. Apart from the invalid html your generating (and the fact that this is not real code - in future copy the real code) `alert($(".country")[0].selectedIndex)` will return the index of the first dropdown, not the dropdown inside the div that you have clicked on

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanku for your information.Here after does't use selectlist

Comment: Not really sure what the point of this code is - your binding to a property of your model but it wont be able to post back to the model (only the first dropdown will bind so your code does not make sense) but if you do want to do this, at least add `new { id = "" }` so it removed the `id` attribute (duplicate `id` attributes are invalid html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest) parent like,

```
$("#maindiv").on("click ", ".remove ", function (e) {
    var $parent =$(this).closest('div'); // cache parent
    alert($parent.find('.country')[0].selectedIndex);
    $parent.remove();
});
```

Snippet

```js
$("#maindiv").on("click ", ".remove ", function (e) {
    var $parent =$(this).closest('div'); // cache parent
    alert($parent.find('.country')[0].selectedIndex);
    $parent.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="maindiv">
  <!-- id must be unique, so using class -->
  <div class="subdiv">
    <select class="country">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="1">India</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="remove" class="remove">
  </div>
  <div class="subdiv">
    <select class="country">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="2">USA</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="remove" class="remove">
  </div>
  <div class="subdiv">
    <select class="country">
      <option>Select</option>
      <option value="3">Australia</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="remove" class="remove">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `option:selected` to get selected option

```
$('.country option:selected').index();
```

**Code**

```
$("#maindiv").on("click ", ".remove ", function (e) {
    alert($('.country option:selected').index());
    $this.parent('div').remove();
});
```

Comment: @ManoJohnbritto Check with `text()` instead of `value`

Comment: @ManoJohnbritto To get the selected option index you can use `index()`. Check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Selected(country){
    alert(country);
}

@html.dropdownlistfor(m=>m.id,new selectlist((viewbag.country) as selectlist,"Value","Text"),new{ @onchange="Selected(this.value)"})
```